# How to get all records from the last 7 days sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I am trying to get all records from a mysql Database with sequelize and I have tried following approaches:

```
shops.findAndCountAll({
  where: {
    createdAt: {
      [Op.gte]: moment().subtract(7, 'days').toDate()
    }
  }
})
```

and when I use this, I get the error:
`ReferenceError: moment is not defined`

So I tried this approach:

```
shops.findAndCountAll({
  where: {
    createdAt: {
      [Op.gte]: Sequelize.literal('NOW() - INTERVAL "7d"'),
    }
  }
})
```

But I get the following error

```
code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
    errno: 1064,
    sqlState: '42000',
    sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 

your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1",
        sql: "SELECT count(*) AS `count` FROM `shop` AS `shops` WHERE `shops`.`createdAt` >= NOW() - INTERVAL '7d';"
      },
      sql: "SELECT count(*) AS `count` FROM `shop` AS `shops` WHERE `shops`.`createdAt` >= NOW() - INTERVAL '7d';"
    }
```

How can I fix this issue. I do not mind which of the approaches I use, as long as I get it to work.

Thank you in advance

Comment: import moment for the first error? also you are adding to the string

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not importing `moment` ; therefore `moment` is not defined.

try

```
const moment = require('moment') //<es6
```

or

```
import moment from 'moment'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using DATE_ADD() or DATE_SUB()

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Name
WHERE connect_time >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -7 DAY);
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Name
WHERE connect_time >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

Without those functions, you can also do

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Name
WHERE connect_time >= (CURDATE() + INTERVAL -7 DAY);
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Name
WHERE connect_time >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have get the result in the second approach by following this

```
const dayCount = '7d';

shops.findAndCountAll({
  where: {
    createdAt: {
      [Op.gte]: Sequelize.literal(`NOW() - INTERVAL '${dayCount}'`),
    }
  }
})
```

you can reuse this logic for any date ranges by changing `dayCount` param